# AWS EC2 cloud9 environment - retrieving project files outside environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloud9

I’ve recently been developing in AWS cloud 9 in an effort to move away from a local environment, and everything has been going well until I wake up this morning and cannot get into the environment. Something to do with the vCPUs credits.

How does one retrieve project files that were stored in the environment without accessing the environment directly? I cannot see any documentation anywhere. I’ve been running on an EC2 T3 instance if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

You can just SSH/SCP to the EC2 instance that runs your Cloud9 environment. You'll need to put the *public* key on the instance if it's not there already.